# How can I get the current form in a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a Windows Forms application. I want to get the processing form (current form) in that application from another application. Because the (first) application consists of multiple forms, I want to know which form is processing/active.

Comment: Do you want to know the current Form from within the same application? If so, the answer of Daniel will certainly do. If you want to access this from another application, you'll have to work with Win32 programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***`GetForegroundWindow`***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505.aspx) function

> Retrieves a handle to the foreground window (the window with which the user is currently working).

C# Signature:

```
/// <summary>The GetForegroundWindow function returns a handle to the foreground window.</summary>
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

and s sample code from pinvoke:

```
public ApplicationState AppState
{
    get
    {
        Process[] processCollection = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName);
        if(processCollection != null && processCollection.Length  >= 1 && 
            processCollection[0] != null)
        {
            IntPtr activeWindowHandle = Win32.GetForegroundWindow();
            //Optional int ProcessID;
            //Optional Win32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(),out ProcessID)
            foreach(Process wordProcess in processCollection)
            {
                //Optional if( ProcessID == wordProcess.Id ) return ApplicationState.Focused;
                if(wordProcess.MainWindowHandle == activeWindowHandle)
                {
                    return ApplicationState.Focused;
                }
            }
            return ApplicationState.Running;
        }
        return ApplicationState.NotRunning;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using another application?

So app B has to access the processing form of app A? And at runtime, A and B are distinct processes, aren't they? So app A should expose a kind of a listening socket accessible from app B and an api with a method such as `GetCurrentForm()`. So app B can send a request to the socket and obtain the response. I figure out something like this.

References:

- [Socket at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx)

Comment: I want to get active form in another application using my appliction